# What is the best way to generate this power series expansion?

Tags: series-expansion

```
f[m_, z_] := (1/m)*Sum[Exp[z*Exp[2*Pi*I/m]^k], {k, 0, m - 1}]
g[t_] := 1/(2 - f[5, t^(1/5)])
Series[g[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

When I tried to compute this on Wolfram Programming Cloud
I got the message: "The Wolfram Engine has been terminated because the evaluation time limit was reached."

Perhaps the function `g` can be rewritten in a simpler form (a sum of trigonometric terms)?

Comment: Is `i` supposed to be imaginary i?  If so it needs to be `I` (capital letter).

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121363)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be noted that the [Mittag-Leffler function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mittag-LefflerFunction.html) is built-in:

```
f[m_, z_] := MittagLefflerE[m, z^m]
g[t_] := 1/(2 - f[5, t^(1/5)])
Series[g[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

which yields the same series as in the Wizard's answer. If you are using an older version that does not yet support `MittagLefflerE[]`, here is an alternative:

```
f[m_, z_] := HypergeometricPFQ[{}, Range[m - 1]/m, (z/m)^m]
g[t_] := 1/(2 - f[5, t^(1/5)])
Series[g[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 4):

My best guess as to what you want:

```
f[m_, z_] := (1/m)*Sum[Exp[z*Exp[2*Pi*I/m]^k], {k, 0, m - 1}]

g[t_] := 1/(2 - f[5, t^(1/5)]);

Series[ExpToTrig @ g[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> 1 + t/120 + (253 t^2)/3628800 + (762763 t^3)/1307674368000 + (
>  43173223 t^4)/8846916393369600 + (633287284180541 t^5)/15511210043330985984000000 + (
>  633594892177711781 t^6)/1854915103581755654799360000000 + (
>  29529277377602939454694793 t^7)/10333147966386144929666651337523200000000 + (
>  118226228593807528558241820049 t^8)/4944941110593319602094613755127975116800000000 + \
> (1259341493633888212897976517963115369 t^9)/
>   6295906361341062871682271657666195529704407040000000000 + \
> (107604770495341349966501435996477524098581 t^10)/
>   64300408460281983178885006693583020812637720018944000000000000
> ```

(I used [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) on the output for the sake of copying.)